# python(pyodbc):Run ms access query from python results to size error

Tags: python, ms-access-2010, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc and pandas on python 3.5 in order to load ~10000 rows of data from MS Access 2010 into a data frame and calculate some correlations afterwards.

When I try the below code to see what the generator does, the code is printing about 9600 expected rows  out of the ~10000 and then I get the bellow error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The query cannot be
>   completed. Either the size of the query is larger than the maximum
>   size of a database (2 GB), or there is not enough temporary storage
>   space on the disk to store the query result.

```
**Code:**

Import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

con = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
                     r'DBQ=MyDB.mdb;')
cur - con.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * from [query table]" # I have a query table which is pivoting the data inside the access.

def gen(cursor, sql):
   cursor.execute(sql)
   While True:
       row = cursor.fetchone()
       if row is None:
           break
       yield row

for x in gen(cur,sql):
    print(x)
```

I have defined another function, which gets the generator's row and appends them to list and then to pd.Dataframe, but it seems that the generator is not completing the job.

I compacted and repaired the database but no luck. Also, the size of the mdb file is not more than 500mb at the moment.

Can you please let me know how can I overcome this error?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps try `con.autocommit = True` immediately after your call to `pyodbc.connect`

Comment: Thanks a lot Gord - It worked!! Would you like to let me know (for my understanding) how this fixed my issue? Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When establishing a connection, pyodbc defaults to `autocommit=False` in accordance with Python's DB-API spec. Therefore when the first SQL statement is executed, ODBC begins a database transaction that remains in effect until the Python code does a `.commit()` or a `.rollback()` on the connection.

Apparently as you were processing the rows in your result set the Access Database Engine was accumulating more and more information about the "transaction", eventually causing an out-of-memory error. Setting the pyodbc connection to `autocommit=True` told the Access Database Engine not to bother keeping track of any transaction-related information, thus avoiding the error.

Comment: Many thanks Gord for the thourough explanation. Much appreciated.